# How to extend CardboardActivity and ActionBarActivity

Tags: android, android-activity, extend, google-cardboard

In order to use cardboard video (CardboardView), I have to extend CardboardActivity. [Correct me if I am wrong].

However, if I want to use my Activity to extend ActionBarActivity, then how to display CardboardView in the ActionBarActivity?

Comment: try this sample code on github... https://github.com/raasun/cardboard

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use cardboard view you can implement that view in actvity and fragment. There is no need of extends **Cardboard Activity**

Use **VRVideoView**.

**XML:**

```
<com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.widgets.video.VrVideoView
      android:id="@+id/video_view"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:scrollbars="@null"
      android:layout_height="250dip"/>
```

**Android:**

```
private VrVideoView videoWidgetView;

videoWidgetView = (VrVideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_view);
videoWidgetView.setEventListener(new ActivityEventListener());
videoWidgetView.loadVideoFromAsset("congo.mp4");

private class ActivityEventListener extends VrVideoEventListener  {



@Override
public void onLoadSuccess() {

}


@Override
public void onLoadError() {

}

@Override
public void onClick() { 
}


@Override
public void onNewFrame() {

}

@Override
public void onCompletion() {

}
}
```

This is the main code for video view. Use this code for your reference. 
reference [link](https://developers.google.com/vr/android/reference/com/google/vr/sdk/widgets/video/VrVideoView#public-methods_2),Try [this](https://developers.google.com/vr/android/samples/vrview#vr_view_sample_apps).

**NOTE:**
Using **Cardboard Activity** is based upon your requirements.

**Some examples**:if you want to use **magnetic trigger** in google cardboard you need to extends **cardboard activity**.

Read this [too](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/vr_view_app_101/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#9).